# Unity, MacOS, cannot load audio from StreamingAssets using www.SendWebRequest()

Tags: c#, macos, unity-game-engine

I am working on an app targeting Windows, built in Unity.
All the audio files are in streamingAssets so the client can replace them and customize the app.
I have the following code loading the audio files into Audio Sources and it's working fine on Windows.

```
void SetAudioFromStreamingAssets()
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(StreamingAssetFilePath)) return;
    string fullpath = Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/" + StreamingAssetFilePath;
    if (!File.Exists(fullpath)) return;

    StartCoroutine(SetAudioClipFromFile(source,fullpath));
}

IEnumerator SetAudioClipFromFile(AudioSource audioSource, string path)
{
    using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequestMultimedia.GetAudioClip(path, AudioType.UNKNOWN))
    {
        yield return www.SendWebRequest();
        if (www.isNetworkError)
        {
            VisDebug.AppendTxt("ERROR. Could not load music file: " + www.error, true);
        }
        else
        {
            AudioClip myClip = DownloadHandlerAudioClip.GetContent(www);
            audioSource.clip = myClip;
        }
    }
}
```

A colleage of mine is trying to work on the project but he only has a mac. And the audio is not loading on his mac.
The code is reaching this line..

```
VisDebug.AppendTxt("ERROR. Could not load music file: " + www.error, true);
```

So File.Exists is true, and also www.isNetworkError is true.
and the www.error is...

> Cannot connect to destination host

### EDIT

The answer below is correct and just fyi here is an example of what the path needs to look like on macos.

> file:///Users/spoopy/Documents/GitHub/Thing/Assets/StreamingAssets/GameLoad.wav

Comment: Perhaps the variable path is not as expected. Bit confused as you said you’re building for windows but the title says mac.   Also path.combine works better than manual manipulation

Comment: @BugFinder if the path was wrong then File.Exists would be false.

Comment: Depends on the path. Because c:\\myfile exists. But thats not a web url :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to prefix your path with `file://` on MacOS and Linux.

You could put something like this after your variable definition or just before `.SendWebRequest()`.

```
#if UNITY_STANDALONE_OSX || UNITY_EDITOR_OSX
    fullpath = "file://" + path;
#endif
```

[Source](https://forum.unity.com/threads/loading-from-streaming-assets-with-unitywebrequest-fails-on-mac.881389/)

Comment: So if I use your code "file://" never gets appended. I also tried adding it manually, in order to get a path like this...  file://Users/bm/Documents/GitHub/Killatron/Assets/StreamingAssets/GameLoad.wav   and I get a different error "Malformed URL"

Comment: Where did you add my lines? It should work but only when your projects platform is set to MacOS Standalone.

Your resulting URI should look like this:
file:///Users/bm/Documents/GitHub/Killatron/Assets/StreamingAssets/GameLoad.wav
Note the additional slash as the first character of your path is / before adding `file://`

Comment: I tested on a mac and yeah that combine LOC just does nothing. I will try with 3 slashes after file now...

Comment: So path.Combine does nothing in case. But this fixes the issue.
#if UNITY_STANDALONE_OSX || UNITY_EDITOR_OSX        
        path = "file://"+ path;
#endif
If you update upir answer I will mark it accepted (u forgot to put if in 1st compiler flag line btw)

Comment: I have made the changes. Good it’s working for you now.